# Correct Elixir Syntax Highlighting

Tags: listings, syntax-highlighting

I am currently writing a thesis in which I frequently need to add Elixir code snippets. I am not very experienced with LaTeX, but after a bit of searching I found [this solution](https://gist.github.com/m1dnight/95f405c9c41f208a16df0a68b6ccbfda).

The problem is that this solution is not perfect. Keywords need to be followed by at least one space, which is undesirable as they are often immediatly followed by comma's or different kinds of brackets in real code. If there is no space, these comma's or brackets are highlighted as a keyword as well. Additionally, when a line ends with a keyword, spaces seem to have no effect and the color highlighting of the keyword continues on the next line.

**Here is an example of how it looks like:**

[image]

**Here is the relevant LaTeX code:**

```
\definecolor{commentgreen}{RGB}{2,112,10}
\definecolor{eminence}{RGB}{108,48,130}
\definecolor{weborange}{RGB}{255,165,0}
\definecolor{frenchplum}{RGB}{129,20,83}

\lstdefinelanguage{elixir}{
    morekeywords={case,catch,def,do,else,false,%
        use,alias,receive,timeout,defmacro,defp,%
        for,if,import,defmodule,defprotocol,%
        nil,defmacrop,defoverridable,defimpl,%
        super,fn,raise,true,try,end,with,%
        unless},
    otherkeywords={<-,->,|>},
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{\#},
    morecomment=[n]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[s][\color{purple}]{:}{\ },
    morestring=[s][\color{orange}]"",
    commentstyle=\color{commentgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{eminence},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines,
    showstringspaces=false,
    frame=tb,
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=elixir] 
pid = spawn(SimpleScoreboard, :loop , [0])
>> {:ok, <PID>}
 
send(pid, {:add, 50})
>> :ok    
 
send(pid, {:sub, 8})
>> :ok  
 
send(pid, :showscore)     
>> :ok
>> 42
\end{lstlisting}
```

How would one solve this issue? I am also open to other alternatives to add Elixir code snippets to my LaTeX document, if there are better solutions.

Comment: Please, as usual here, show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: The code I am using is in the link I provided, but I will add it explicitly to the question as well.

Comment: What @Mensch meant was: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) instead of listings:

```
\begin{minted}{elixir}
pid = spawn(SimpleScoreboard, :loop , [0])
>> {:ok, <PID>}
 
send(pid, {:add, 50})
>> :ok    
 
send(pid, {:sub, 8})
>> :ok  
 
send(pid, :showscore)     
>> :ok
>> 42
\end{minted}
```

[image]